# How to make only some strings of nested lists into integers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, nested-lists

So currently I'm trying to take a nested list with data and convert some of the elements of those lists into integers. So right now the nested list prints this:

```
def Top5_Bottom5_test():
    with open("Population.txt", "r") as in_file:
        nested = [line.strip().split(',') for line in in_file][1:] #This creates the nested list
        nested[0:][1:] = [int(x) for x in nested[0][1:]] #This is what I'm trying to use to make the numbers in the lists into integers.
        print nested
```

This prints:

```
[['Alabama', '126', '79', '17'], ['Alaska', '21', '100', '10'], ['Arizona', '190', '59', '16'], ['Arkansas', '172', '49', '28']....]
```

But what I'm trying to get it to output so I can use bubble sorting is:

```
[['Alabama', 126, 79, 17], ['Alaska', 21, 100, 10], ['Arizona', 190, 59, 16], ['Arkansas', 172, 49, 28]....]
```

With this my endgoal is to get the lists sorted by the [1]th element in descending order but I can't seem to do it while they're in string form. Trying to avoid using sort() and sorted() functions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nested = [line.strip().split(',') for line in in_file][1:]
nested = [line[:1] + [int(x) for x in line[1:]] for line in nested]
```

The trick is using list slices to process separately the first element and the rest of the elements in each line.

Comment: Seems to yield the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't'".

Comment: @JohnathanScott I updated my answer, if it's still failing - are you sure that the input data looks as the sample in the question? it seems that some element (after the first one) in some line is _not_ an integer.

Comment: The first line in the .txt file I'm importing i was ignoring in the code i had above because its just the legend so to speak. Normally its just a text file with
Alabama,1,2,3
Alaska,2,5,3
etc...
But the code i had split it into the nested list.

Comment: OK, you should have mentioned that :) . It's fixed now.

Comment: You are a saint, thank you so much! :) just learning python right now and omg is it frustrating haha